# Is it possible to infer a type that is a reflection-like closure?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, higher-rank-types, clash

With the following "toy model" of Clash:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, KindSignatures, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts #-}

-- Simplified model of platform definitions
data Domain = DomSys | Dom25

data Signal (dom :: Domain)
data Clock (dom :: Domain)

class HiddenClock (dom :: Domain)

withClock :: Clock dom -> (HiddenClock dom => r) -> r
withClock _ _ = undefined
```

I would like to use `withClock` to close over the `HiddenClock` constraint inside a local `where` block. Suppose I have the following two toplevel definitions:

```
-- Simplified model of external standalone definitions
mainBoard :: (HiddenClock dom) => Signal dom -> Signal dom -> Signal dom -> (Signal dom, Signal dom)
mainBoard = undefined

peripherals :: (HiddenClock dom) => Signal dom -> Signal dom
peripherals = undefined

video
    :: Clock domVid
    -> Clock domSys
    -> Signal domSys
    -> Signal domSys
    -> (Signal domVid, Signal domSys, Signal domSys)
video = undefined
```

then, I would like to write something like the following:

```
topEntity :: Clock Dom25 -> Clock DomSys -> Signal DomSys -> Signal Dom25
topEntity clkVid clkSys input = vga
  where
    (vga, vidRead, line) = video clkVid clkSys vidAddr vidWrite
    (vidAddr, vidWrite) = withClock clkSys board

    board = mainBoard vidRead line p
      where
        p = peripherals input
```

Unfortunately, GHC (at least as of 8.10.7) is unable to infer the correct type for `board`, which causes `withClock clkSys board` to not really close over the `HiddenClock DomSys` constriant:

```
    • No instance for (HiddenClock 'DomSys)
        arising from a use of ‘mainBoard’
    • In the expression: mainBoard vidRead line p
      In an equation for ‘board’:
          board
            = mainBoard vidRead line p
            where
                p = peripherals input
      In an equation for ‘topEntity’:
          topEntity clkVid clkSys input
            = vga
            where
                (vga, vidRead, line) = video clkVid clkSys vidAddr vidWrite
                (vidAddr, vidWrite) = withClock clkSys board
                board
                  = mainBoard vidRead line p
                  where
                      p = peripherals input
   |
38 |     board = mainBoard vidRead line p
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    • No instance for (HiddenClock 'DomSys)
        arising from a use of ‘peripherals’
    • In the expression: peripherals input
      In an equation for ‘p’: p = peripherals input
      In an equation for ‘board’:
          board
            = mainBoard vidRead line p
            where
                p = peripherals input
   |
40 |         p = peripherals input
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This can be worked around by adding a type signature to `board`:

```
    board :: (HiddenClock DomSys) => (Signal DomSys, Signal DomSys)
```

My question is: **is it possible to change this code slightly, or fiddle with the exact type of `withClock` etc., to make this definition of `topEntity` typecheck without a type signature on the binding of `board`?**

Comment: I assume (1) you know that it type checks fine if the `board` and `p` definitions are folded into the `withClock` call; and (2) you aren't interested in solutions that make the dictionary more explicit in the `mainBoard` and `peripherals` calls (e.g., `Dict` from the `constraints` package).

Comment: @K.A.Buhr these assumptions are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really infer this and I'm not entirely sure why you need to.
In Clash `HiddenClock` uses `ImplicitParams` under the hood. Currently, your `board` has no way of knowing where the clock is coming from.

You need to either pass the clock by value `clkSys` or explicitly write that the clock is needed at the type level with a `HiddenClock` constraint.

`ImplicitParams` don't really work like normal type class constraints. This `HiddenClock` isn't a constraint on the `dom`. And you can see that by the fact that `HiddenClock 'DomSys` is still needed as a constraint, even though it has no free variables.

Here is an example using plain Haskell (with `ImplicitParams`) of your issue:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Temp where

withX :: Int -> ((?x :: Int) => r) -> r
withX x r =
  let ?x = x
  in r

somethingThanNeedsX :: (?x :: Int) => Int
somethingThanNeedsX = ?x + 2

foo :: Int
foo = bar
  where
    bar = withX 42 baz

    baz = somethingThanNeedsX
```

And GHC tells me:

```
Orig.hs:19:11: error:
    • Unbound implicit parameter (?x::Int)
        arising from a use of ‘somethingThanNeedsX’
    • In the expression: somethingThanNeedsX
      In an equation for ‘baz’: baz = somethingThanNeedsX
      In an equation for ‘foo’:
          foo
            = bar
            where
                bar = withX 42 baz
                baz = somethingThanNeedsX
   |
19 |     baz = somethingThanNeedsX
   |
```

In order to make this work, you either need to have `withX` in the definition of `baz` (explicitly passing x/the clock there) or be explicit about the `ImplicitParams` dependency. You don't need a full type signature if you don't want to, you just need the `ImplicitParams` constraint (using `PartialTypeSignatures`):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

module Temp where

withX :: Int -> ((?x :: Int) => r) -> r
withX x r =
  let ?x = x
  in r

somethingThanNeedsX :: (?x :: Int) => Int
somethingThanNeedsX = ?x + 2

foo :: Int
foo = bar
  where
    bar = withX 42 baz

    baz :: (?x :: Int) => _
    baz = somethingThanNeedsX
```

This now compiles just fine (with a warning that can be disabled with `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-partial-type-signatures #-}` if you really want):

```
Temp.hs:20:27: warning: [-Wpartial-type-signatures]
    • Found type wildcard ‘_’ standing for ‘Int’
    • In the type signature: baz :: (?x :: Int) => _
      In an equation for ‘foo’:
          foo
            = bar
            where
                bar = withX 42 baz
                baz :: (?x :: Int) => _
                baz = somethingThanNeedsX
    • Relevant bindings include foo :: Int (bound at Temp.hs:16:1)
   |
20 |     baz :: (?x :: Int) => _
   |
```

Comment: If Clash is compiled with `multiple-hidden` set to `False`, shouldn't that help inferring the type of `board`? After all, it's using `HiddenClock DomSys` and we know there can't be other hidden clocks around (because of no `multiple-hidden`).

Comment: Shouldn't enabling the `NoMonorphisationRestriction` allow it to typecheck without signature? I tried it and it doesn't help. But I at least intuitively thought that with it enabled it should be able to infer that the unsolved constraint should remain in the type.

Comment: `NoMonorphisationRestriction` only works on the free type variables to ensure they don't become a concrete type. It doesn't do anything about constraints. Enabling it does usually help when the constraints are constraints on a free variable but this isn't the case here.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why GHC can't infer the `ImplicitParams` constraints, but my guess is that it's not necessarily something `baz` depends on. We could just as well add that `ImplicitParams` constraint to `foo` and it would just work (ignoring the `withX 42`, but that just goes to show `ImplicitParams` is flawed).

Comment: `multiple-hidden` is irrelevant for this issue, as I am showing in my example, we can replicate your issue with basic use of `ImplicitParams`.

If you look at how it is setup: https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/blob/66b40ebfc9ec3ee341fbecf58585c6e00f0f9f5b/clash-prelude/src/Clash/Signal.hs#L548-L556
You can see that the only real thing `multiple-hidden` does is to make the name of the `ImplicitParams` variable `?clock`, also use the name of the domain. This way when you have `HiddenClock domA` and `HiddenClock domB` they don't both use `?clock` but `?domA_clk` and `?domB_clk`.